# Added items to a database, but SSRS report does not appear to see them

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

This is a very strange and perplexing problem I have never run across.  I am working on an SSRS report that feeds off a database.  I use an SSIS extraction package to append data to a table in said database.  Everything seemed to work fine until the first time I updated the table.  I can see the new data in SSMS, but the report looks like it is only seeing the data I had in there prior to the update.  I've restarted Visual Studio, checked the connection string, and checked my dataset queries and I have no clue why the report is doing what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are editing the report in Visual Studio, yes, it can be overly aggressive about caching the results of queries.

Look in the Solution folder (in file explorer, not Visual Studio) and look for a file with the name of the report, but `.data` appended, such as `Report1.rdl.data`.

Delete that file, which you can do while VS is running. Then preview the report again.

Comment: I shall remember that for next time.  I ran the report again before I saw your answer and it was working correctly.

Comment: if you change any parameter of the report while running in Visual Studio, it will go to the db and get the data again (ie recreating/resetting the .data file)